# XML org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName vs Regex pattern matcher

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Which approach is better in terms of space and time complexity to find count of list of xml element names from XML data.
The xml data will be of 2 GB.
List of xml element names to be searched will be around 30.

approach 1:

```
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes());
    Document doc = db.parse(bis);

    NodeList xList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xTag");
```

approach 2:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
    while (matcher.find())
        count++;
```

```
for example :
            <x>
        <Element1>
           <Employee>
              <Name>Name</Name>
              <BirthDate>1968-01-01</BirthDate>
              <Gender>female</Gender>
           </Employee>
           <Element2 Type="D">
              <Element3>1000.00</Element3>
           </Element2>
           <Services Type="K">
              <Element4>1000.00</Element4>
           </Services>
        </Element1>
        <Element1>
           <Employee>
              <Name>Name</Name>
              <BirthDate>1968-01-01</BirthDate>
              <Gender>female</Gender>
           </Employee>
           <Element2 Type="D">
              <Element3>1000.00</Element3>
           </Element2>
        </Element1>
            </x>

count output :
    Element1 - 2
    Employee - 2
    Element2 - 2
    Services - 1
```

Could you please suggest which approach is better ?
org.w3c.dom.Document.getElementsByTagName or Regex pattern matcher

Comment: A regex is never a good solution for parsing XML. XML is too complex for several reasons, one of them is nesting. Out of these two options, I'd go for `Document.getElementsByTagName`. However, both solutions will have issues with files that large. There is another option: use SAX or StAX parsing from a `Reader` or `InputStream. Then you won't have to hold the entire document in memory. See https://www.baeldung.com/java-sax-parser and https://www.baeldung.com/java-stax for more information.

Comment: Correctness always comes before performance. You might succeed in writing a regex-based solution that works on one example file, but it will have bugs that show up when given other equally valid XML files. For a correct solution, you need to use an XML parser. Having said that, there are much better tools in the Java world than DOM.